# Is there a distinction between saying Relationship Extraction and Relation Extraction in NLP

Tags: nlp

A decade ago or so, I was doing a lot of Information Extraction (IE) with Stanford CoreNLP.  One of the tasks of the IE pipeline with that tool is Relation Extraction.  Relations are still very important, although we capture them with other techniques now.  There are some people out there that talk about Relationship Extraction which always confuses me. I generally talk about Relation Extraction when doing NLP.  Is there any distinction between Relation Extraction and Relationship Extraction?  Are they two distinct tasks, or do they generally refer to the same task?